# Как установить PHP 5.5 на macOS?

Tags: php, macos

Если не ошибаюсь с macOS сразу идет PHP, но новый. У меня стоит локальный сервер MAMP и он отображает версию 7. Мне же нужен PHP версии 5.5. Как установить PHP 5.5 на macOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте поставить виртуальную машину Homestead от Laravel https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/homestead, там из коробки идут 5.6 7.0 и 7.1 с удобной возможностью переключения между ними.

Если нужна конкретно версия 5.5 то можно поставить `brew` https://brew.sh и уже через него поставить php55 formulae.brew.sh/formula/php55

```
brew install php55
```